# My version of Heroku doesn't offer pg:backups:download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide

I'm using Cloud9 IDE. According to the heroku version command, I'm running

```
heroku-toolbelt/3.43.13 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.3.0
heroku-cli/5.4.8-eee5ec9 (linux-amd64) go1.7.1
```

with no installed plugins.

I'm trying to download the database from one of my production apps to use in another. In doing so, I get the error,

```
`pg:backups:download` is not a heroku command
```

When I run heroku help, my list shows "pgbackups" as a valid command, not "pg:backups", which is what I should see, according to the latest documentation.

When I run heroku help pgbackups, it lists options for capture, restore, destroy, transfer, and url.

Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

Please install new verion of heroku Cli, ref link: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Since in your list show 'pgbackups'
it means your are using older version which consists of pgbackups addon that got deprecated.
ref link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/623

You can create a publicly accessible backup URL with the pg:backups:url command. When the command is specified without a backup id, the latest available backup URL will be returned. This is useful for exporting your data outside of Heroku Postgres:

```
1) List you backups
   heroku pg:backups --app your_app_name 

2) heroku pg:backups:url b001 --app your_app_name
```

after this you will get this output which consist of url

The following URL will expire at 2015-04-07 18:35:50 +0000:
"http://s3.amazonaws.com/xkpgbackups/app1234567@heroku.com/b004.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=ABCD1234&Expires=1289261668&Signature=3mMBeKISewgEUDT%2FL5mRz4EYS4M%3D"

you can then download the dump by clicking on the url.

Comment: This seems like it is probably a correct answer. So far, however, I am unable to re-install or update my version of heroku on Cloud9 IDE. The gentleman at this link: https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-update-heroku-cli/12074/6 seemed to have the same problem, but his solution didn't work for me. I will try asking a different question to try to figure out how to update my heroku. And then I'll get back to following the rest of your directions.